# returning PyBytes from async function in pyo3 and pyo3_asyncio

Tags: rust, pyo3

I have the following working implementation for reading bytes from a datachannel and returning the bytes as a list in the python interop:

```rust
    fn read<'a>(&self, py: Python<'a>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
        let mut dc = self.datachannel.clone();
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; 2048 as usize];
        
        pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
            let n = dc.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            assert!(n < 2048);
            Ok(buf[..n].to_vec())
        })
    }
```

However, I would like this function to return the raw bytes as [`PyBytes`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/types/struct.PyBytes.html) instead. My initial thought was to do as the following

```rust
    fn read<'a>(&self, py: Python<'a>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
        let mut dc = self.datachannel.clone();
        let mut buf = vec![0u8; 2048 as usize];
        
        pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
            let n = dc.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            assert!(n < 2048);
            let py_bytes = PyBytes::new(py, &buf[..n]);
            Ok(py_bytes.into())
        })
    }
```

but I am getting the compile error:

```
37  |           pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
    |  _________-----------------------------------_____^
    | |         |
    | |         required by a bound introduced by this call
38  | |             let n = dc.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
39  | |             assert!(n < 2048);
40  | |             let py_bytes = PyBytes::new(py, &buf[..n]);
41  | |             Ok(py_bytes.into())
42  | |         })
    | |_________^ `*mut pyo3::Python<'static>` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

How do I make the read function return PyBytes?

Comment: I'm no expert, but the [py03-asyncio documentation](https://docs.rs/pyo3-asyncio/latest/pyo3_asyncio/index.html) always uses `Python::with_gil` to construct the return value. It doesn't try to use the original `py`. EDIT: probably because async tasks need to be cooperative and not hold the GIL the whole time the task is executing.

Comment: I tried using the python GIL with `Ok(Python::with_gil(|py| PyBytes::new(py, &buf[..n])))` but I am getting instead that the lifetime may not live long enough since the lifetime of py does not match the lifetime of the return value from `PyBytes::new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a handle to `py` means holding the global interpreter lock (GIL) which you should avoid with asynchronous tasks or else they lose their cooperative nature.

Instead you should use `Python::with_gil` to reacquire the GIL to construct the result. To return a `PyBytes` from this, you must un-link it from the new `py` reference which you can do by turning it into a `PyObject`.

Give this a try:

```
use pyo3::ToPyObject;

fn read<'a>(&self, py: Python<'a>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
    let mut dc = self.datachannel.clone();
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; 2048 as usize];
    
    pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
        let n = dc.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
        assert!(n < 2048);
        Python::with_gil(|py| Ok(PyBytes::new(py, &buf[..n]).to_object(py)))
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "concurrent nature" instead of "cooperative nature". I don't see how the cooperativeness i.e. the need to explicitly `await` rather than preemptive scheduling gets lost by holding a GIL. Maybe I've mixed up some terms?

Comment: @cafce25 I worded it that way because holding the GIL would not be "cooperating" with the rest of the Python system (in the traditional sense of the word). But you're right in the technical sense since "cooperative multitasking" usually just requires yielding.